# Find if already exists, JS and Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I have an interesting issue I am not sure how to follow, I need to use lodash to search two arrays in an object, looking to see if x already exists, lets look at a console out put:

[image]

There are two keys I am interested in: `questChains` and `singleQuests`, I want to write two seperate functions using lodash to say: find me id x in the array of objects where `questChains` `questChainID` is equal to x.

The second function would say: Find me a quest in the array of objects where `singleQuests` `questTitle` equals y

So if we give an example, you can see that `questChainId` is a `1` so if I pass in a 1 to said function I would get `true` back, I don't actually care about the object its self, else I would get false.

The same goes for `singleQuests`, If I pass in `hello` (case insensitive) I would get back `true` because there is a quest with the `questTitle` of 'Hello'. Again I don't care about the object coming back.

The way I would write this is something like:

```
_.find(theArray, function(questObject){
    _.find(questObject.questChains, function(questChain){
         if (questChain.questChainId === 1) {
             return true;
         }
    });
});
```

This is just for the quest chain id comparison. This seems super messy, why? Because I am nesting lodash find, I am also nesting if. It gets a bit difficult to read.

Is this the only way to do this? or is there a better way?

Comment: Since you chose to provide a screenshot instead of an executable version of your data, any answers you get will likely be untested. It would be much better for you to provide a `JSON.stringify` version of your data, or a hand-crafted minimal example.

Comment: untested is fine, I am just looking for general concepts of how one might approach this. @Amadan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it can be expressed more simply.

Try something like this:

```js
var exampleArray = [{
  questChains: [{
    questChainId: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    questChainId: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }],
  singleQuests: [{
    questTitle: 'hello world'
  }]
}, {
  questChains: [{
    questChainId: 77,
    name: 'kappa'
  }]
}];

var result = _.chain(exampleArray)
              .pluck('questChains')
              .flatten()
              .findWhere({ questChainId: 2 })
              .value();

console.log('result', result);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using `chain` and `value` is optional. They just let you chain together multiple lodash methods more succinctly.

`pluck` grabs a property from each object in an array and returns a new array of those properties.

`flatten` takes a nested array structure and flattens it into flat array structure.

`findWhere` will return the first element which matches the property name/value provided.

Combining all of these results in us fetching all `questChain` arrays from `exampleArray`, flattening them into a single array which can be more easily iterated upon, and then performing a search for the desired value.

Case-insensitive matching will be slightly more challenging. You'd either need to either replace `findWhere` with a method which accepts a matching function (i.e. `find`) or sanitize your input ahead of time. Either way you're going to need to call `toLower`, `toUpper`, or some variant on your names to standardize your search.